# Access to other contacts groups information

Tags: google-people-api, contactgroups

From Google Contacts web interface you can edit a contact and include her in several groups/tags. Then if you decide to "Hide from contacts", the contact will not be in My contacts anymore, but she still exists in Other contacts, and also you can open her and see the groups.

However, People API don't let to know the groups of Other contacts, since you can only retrieve `names` , `emailsAddresses` and `phoneNumbers`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Aren't groups also email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out that Other contacts have the `resourceName` in the form `otherContacts/<contact-id>`, but if you change it to `people/<contact-id>` (keeping the same contact-id) you can retrieve all the other contact fields with `People.People.get()`